# ng-repeat no output of JSON data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I fill an array of JSON data with person-related data, like this.

```
$scope.persons = [{ firstname: '', surname: ''}];
$scope.persons.push({
   firstname: $scope.firstname, //input form field
   surname: $scope.surname //input form field
});
```

Then I try to output all elements of the array to HTML like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="person in persons">{{person.firstname}} {{person.surname}}</span>
```

What I am getting is an empty pair of `<SPAN>` tags as an output, always to the right amount, means: three names in the array result in three pairs of `<SPAN>` tags but there is no person-data inside?! Why?

Comment: The span you show is under some element for an Angular Controller? Is `$scope.firstname` and `$scope.surname` declared?

Comment: Wire up a fiddle, this code looks fine. You have one empty person in your original array.

Comment: Yeah, declaring `$scope.persons = [{ firstname: '', surname: ''}];` will put an empty one in your array. Just leave it empty.

Comment: Typo: there is no person.lastname in your AngularJs code

Comment: true, that was my fault while transferring the code to this window. my original script does not contain that typo, though...

Comment: I just tested, your code works fine. There may be other errors in somewhere else. Please use console.log() to check if you really get the values for new firstname/lastname from the input fields. In case anyone needs a Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ealonwang/mct63vLg/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason, I couldn't figure out the very nature of the problem, but I stumbled upon a workaround which helped me out. I figured, it might be useful for someone else, so here it goes:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="person in persons">
      <span ng-bind="person.firstname"></span>&nbsp;<span ng-bind="person.surname"></span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any value in person data i.e firstname and lastname. Initialize firstname and lastname values like this:

```
  $scope.persons = [{ firstname: 'Neha', surname: 'Saggam'}];
  $scope.persons.push({
  firstname: $scope.firstname, //input form field
  surname: $scope.surname //input form field
  });
```

Then try! This works for me.